# What Ansible command to list or verify installed modules — whether built-in or add-on?

Tags: ansible

I can't find any info about any command to run, in order to show/confirm what add-on Ansible modules or built-in Ansible modules are installed on my control-node?

Regarding built-ins, I know that there are web-pages that list these things but **surely** they must be version-dependent, which means that I'd need to first verify my local Ansible version and then find a web-page that lists all built-ins for that specific version — i.e., **very** inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

[`ansible-doc --list`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-doc.html).

```
$ ansible-doc --list | head
add_host                                                                            Add a host (and alternatively a group) to the ansible-playbook in-memory ...
amazon.aws.aws_az_info                                                              Gather information about availability zon...
amazon.aws.aws_caller_info                                                          Get information about the user and account being used to make ...
amazon.aws.aws_s3                                                                   manage obje...
amazon.aws.cloudformation                                                           Create or delete an AWS CloudFormat...
amazon.aws.cloudformation_info                                                      Obtain information about an AWS CloudFormat...
amazon.aws.ec2                                                                      create, terminate, start or stop an instan...
amazon.aws.ec2_ami                                                                  Create or destroy an image (AM...
amazon.aws.ec2_ami_info                                                             Gather information about...
amazon.aws.ec2_eni                                                                  Create and optionally attach an Elastic Network Interface (ENI) to an...
```

This can also be used to list available plugins of other types, e.g. to show all lookup plugins you would run `ansible-doc -t lookup --list`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the dictionary of installed collections and modules

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    ansible_doc: /home/admin/.local/bin/ansible-doc
    modules_all: "{{ (out.stdout|from_yaml).keys()|list }}"
    modules_str: |
      {% for i in modules_all %}
      {% set arr = i.split('.') %}
      - {collection: {{ arr[:-1]|join('.')|d('ansible.builtin', true) }}, module: {{ arr[-1] }}}
      {% endfor %}
    modules_grp: "{{ modules_str|from_yaml|groupby('collection') }}"
    collections_list: "{{ modules_grp|map('first') }}"
    modules_lists: "{{ modules_grp|map('last')|map('map', attribute='module') }}"
    collections: "{{ dict(collections_list|zip(modules_lists)) }}"

  tasks:

    - command: "{{ ansible_doc }} -t module -l -j"
      register: out

    - debug:
        var: out.stdout_lines
      when: false
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
      when: false
    - debug:
        var: modules_all
      when: false
    - debug:
        var: modules_str
      when: false
    - debug:
        var: collections.keys()|list|to_yaml
      when: true
    - debug:
        var: collections['ansible.builtin']|to_yaml
      when: true
    - debug:
        var: collections['community.digitalocean']|to_yaml
      when: true
    - debug:
        var: collections['community.general']|to_yaml
      when: true
```

gives the list of the collections

```yaml
  collections.keys()|list|to_yaml: |-
    [amazon.aws, ansible.builtin, ansible.legacy, ansible.netcommon, ansible.posix, ansible.utils,
      ansible.windows, arista.eos, awx.awx, azure.azcollection, check_point.mgmt, chocolatey.chocolatey,
      cisco.aci, cisco.asa, cisco.dnac, cisco.intersight, cisco.ios, cisco.iosxr, cisco.ise,
      cisco.meraki, cisco.mso, cisco.nso, cisco.nxos, cisco.nxos.storage, cisco.ucs, cloud.common,
      cloudscale_ch.cloud, community.aws, community.ciscosmb, community.crypto, community.digitalocean,
      community.dns, community.docker, community.fortios, community.general, community.google,
      community.grafana, community.hashi_vault, community.hrobot, community.kubevirt,
      community.libvirt, community.mongodb, community.mysql, community.network, community.okd,
      community.postgresql, community.proxysql, community.rabbitmq, community.routeros,
      community.sap, community.sap.database.saphana, community.sap.files, community.sap.identity,
      community.sap.system, community.sap_libs, community.skydive, community.sops, community.vmware,
      community.windows, community.zabbix, containers.podman, cyberark.pas, dellemc.enterprise_sonic,
      dellemc.openmanage, dellemc.os10, dellemc.os6, dellemc.os9, dellemc.powerflex, dellemc.unity,
      f5networks.f5_modules, fortinet.fortimanager, fortinet.fortios, frr.frr, gluster.gluster,
      google.cloud, grafana.grafana, hetzner.hcloud, hpe.nimble, ibm.qradar, ibm.spectrum_virtualize,
      infinidat.infinibox, infoblox.nios_modules, inspur.ispim, inspur.sm, junipernetworks.junos,
      kubernetes.core, lowlydba.sqlserver, mellanox.onyx, netapp.aws, netapp.azure, netapp.cloudmanager,
      netapp.elementsw, netapp.ontap, netapp.storagegrid, netapp.um_info, netapp_eseries.santricity,
      netbox.netbox, ngine_io.cloudstack, ngine_io.exoscale, ngine_io.vultr, openstack.cloud,
      openvswitch.openvswitch, ovirt.ovirt, purestorage.flasharray, purestorage.flashblade,
      purestorage.fusion, sensu.sensu_go, servicenow.servicenow, splunk.es, t_systems_mms.icinga_director,
      theforeman.foreman, vmware.vmware_rest, vultr.cloud, vyos.vyos, wti.remote]
```

Modules *ansible.builtin*

```yaml
  collections['ansible.builtin']|to_yaml: |-
    [_include, add_host, apt, apt_key, apt_repository, assemble, assert, async_status,
      blockinfile, command, copy, cron, debconf, debug, dnf, dpkg_selections, expect,
      fail, fetch, file, find, gather_facts, get_url, getent, git, group, group_by, hostname,
      import_playbook, import_role, import_tasks, include_role, include_tasks, include_vars,
      iptables, known_hosts, lineinfile, meta, package, package_facts, pause, ping, pip,
      raw, reboot, replace, rpm_key, script, service, service_facts, set_fact, set_stats,
      setup, shell, slurp, stat, subversion, systemd, systemd_service, sysvinit, tempfile,
      template, unarchive, uri, user, validate_argument_spec, wait_for, wait_for_connection,
      yum, yum_repository]
```

For example, collection *community.digitalocean*

```yaml
  collections['community.digitalocean']|to_yaml: |-
    [digital_ocean, digital_ocean_account_facts, digital_ocean_account_info, digital_ocean_balance_info,
      digital_ocean_block_storage, digital_ocean_cdn_endpoints, digital_ocean_cdn_endpoints_info,
      digital_ocean_certificate, digital_ocean_certificate_facts, digital_ocean_certificate_info,
      digital_ocean_database, digital_ocean_database_info, digital_ocean_domain, digital_ocean_domain_facts,
      digital_ocean_domain_info, digital_ocean_domain_record, digital_ocean_domain_record_info,
      digital_ocean_droplet, digital_ocean_droplet_info, digital_ocean_firewall, digital_ocean_firewall_facts,
      digital_ocean_firewall_info, digital_ocean_floating_ip, digital_ocean_floating_ip_facts,
      digital_ocean_floating_ip_info, digital_ocean_image_facts, digital_ocean_image_info,
      digital_ocean_kubernetes, digital_ocean_kubernetes_info, digital_ocean_load_balancer,
      digital_ocean_load_balancer_facts, digital_ocean_load_balancer_info, digital_ocean_monitoring_alerts,
      digital_ocean_monitoring_alerts_info, digital_ocean_project, digital_ocean_project_info,
      digital_ocean_region_facts, digital_ocean_region_info, digital_ocean_size_facts,
      digital_ocean_size_info, digital_ocean_snapshot, digital_ocean_snapshot_facts, digital_ocean_snapshot_info,
      digital_ocean_spaces, digital_ocean_spaces_info, digital_ocean_sshkey, digital_ocean_sshkey_facts,
      digital_ocean_sshkey_info, digital_ocean_tag, digital_ocean_tag_facts, digital_ocean_tag_info,
      digital_ocean_volume_facts, digital_ocean_volume_info, digital_ocean_vpc, digital_ocean_vpc_info]
```

Top 10

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          Top 10
          ------
          {% for i in range(10) %}
          {{ collections_len_list[i].key }}: {{ collections_len_list[i].value }}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        modules_lists_len: "{{ modules_lists|map('length') }}"
        collections_len: "{{ dict(collections_list|zip(modules_lists_len)) }}"
        collections_len_list: "{{ collections_len|dict2items|sort(attribute='value', reverse=true) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    Top 10
    ------
    fortinet.fortimanager: 994
    fortinet.fortios: 646
    community.general: 571
    cisco.ise: 383
    cisco.dnac: 354
    community.network: 315
    azure.azcollection: 276
    f5networks.f5_modules: 178
    check_point.mgmt: 174
    google.cloud: 170
```

Comment: **NOW** we're getting somewhere!  Thanks, Vladimir!  But now I have another confusion.  I just now proved that, on my control-node the outputs of "`ansible-doc --list`" and of "`ansible-doc -t module -l`" are **precisely** the **same**.  So, I'm left with continuing to wonder what is the difference between a "module" and any of the various types of "plugin", as described by various sources I have found.  But I guess I'll have to learn that simply by spending many hours playing/working with Ansible in various ways.  Thanks again.

Comment: Everything is a plugin. Take a look at the source. For example [community.general](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/tree/main/plugins) plugins.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks again, Vladimir!  I've been wondering about that.  This is a helpful start.